# AWS Redshift IF-ELSE Logic

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I basically want to do the following thing in Redshift but since Redshift does not support procedural statements I am unsure how to achieve my goal:

```
IF EXISTS (select username,accountnumber from table where username={1})
THEN
    IF {0} NOT IN accountnumber 
        update table set accountnumber = 
        accountnumber+=',{0}' where username='{1}'
    END IF
ELSE
    insert into table values({1},{0});
END IF
```

With param 1 being a user id and param 2 being a username

What would be the best way to achieve this in redshift?
Thanks for any help in advance

Running:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (account_number 
varchar(100), username varchar(50));
case when true
update table set accountnumber = accountnumber+=',{0}' 
where username='{1}'
else insert into table values ('{0}','{1}')
end
```

defining true is just for demo purposes. I am getting the following error:

```
---> syntax error at or near "case"
LINE 2: case when 1=1
```

Comment: It's better if you could show us data and what you want to insert exactly. But I posting answer, try to workaround that.

Comment: @django-unchained I have updated my use case to make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `CASE` expression which works similarly to `if-else`.

```
case when new_record = existing_record
update existing_record
else insert new_record
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get a syntax error when running this statement. I have edited the question with the code i tried running

Answer (score 1):

I see that redshift supports `exists` so maybe this will work

```
/* if the row is there it'll update it. If not it won't */
UPDATE Table Set Field='NewValue' Where KeyValue=1

/* if the row is not there it'll insert it */
INSERT INTO Table (KeyValue,Field1,Field2)
SELECT 1,'NewValue','NewValue'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE KeyValue=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The update works! For the insert the not exists does not seem to work. Every time I run the query it inserts new values into redshift

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, it seems like you are trying to do an upsert. You can make use of merge functionality on redshift? You will need to use a temporary table for holding some of the values before you do the insert/update.

Here are some examples from redshift documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-examples.html